# How to populate rooms in outlook appointments dynamically via Outlook plugins?

Tags: .net, outlook, outlook-addin, appointment, officedev

I'm developing an Outlook plugin (VS2013/CSharp/Outlook 2010 AddIn Project) and I need to set programatically the room list that appears when you try to create an appointment.

As far as I know, those rooms are loaded from the active directory, but I need to show them "per-user".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Application.Session.AddressLists.Item("All Rooms")` should do the job.

EDIT: Outlook hardcodes that list - to the best of my knowledge, Outlook looks for the address list exposed by GAL (PR_AB_PROVIDER_ID = MUIDEMSAB) with the 0x200 bit set in the PR_CONTAINER_FLAGS property. You cannot create new GAL containers programmatically, at least not from the client side.

Comment: Excuse me? How does this not provide an answer to the question? The code snippet above retrieves AddressList object corresponding to the "All Rooms" GAL list.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, thanks you for your quick response. Your answer gave me the clue to write the following code, I will edit your answer and mark it as correct.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, actually the collection for "All Rooms" is readonly, is there a way to modify it? Thank you...

Comment: No, "Add Rooms" is hardwired to open the GAL "All Rooms" container.

Comment: So...what you mean is I cannot modify the "All Rooms" container? Is there any way to do that, perhaps creating another "container" programatically via Outlook plugin? is it possible? Thank you...

Comment: No, it is hardcoded - to the best of my knowledge, Outlook looks for the address list exposed by GAL (PR_AB_PROVIDER_ID = MUIDEMSAB) with the 0x200 bit set in the PR_CONTAINER_FLAGS property. You cannot create new GAL containers programmatically, at least not from the client side.